# cakePHP Requested address not found on this server error

Tags: php, cakephp

Ok! This question is directed to the cakePHP ninjas out there. I have just started using cakePHP in my projects after going through their documentation.

I have an action which I want the user to access only via POST request rather then a GET request. In the action I have the like :

```
If($this->request->is('get')){
   throw new MethodNotAllowedException(); 
}
```

And this works... (it displays the relevant message)
However, an error still occurs, telling me that the requested address is not found on the server.Now I understand why its happening, but I would like to know how I should tackle it within cake.. Any remarks appreciated !

---Edit---
Specific Question : How can I catch the error with cakePHP ? please help if you can, even if you feel that this is very trivial for you!

Comment: There is a typo in your code. You forgot `new`. `throw new MethodNotAllowedException();`

Comment: So now your action accepts POST only. So what is the problem?

Comment: @vooD I was expecting an answer something like the one  cornelb provided! thanks for your time..In retrospect, I think I was not very clear in my question.. As this was not an actual bug I needed to address.. more like a helping hand to understand better the framework!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the view for the error page [Exception Renderer](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#exception-renderer)

Comment: Thanks cornelb, I believe its what I was looking for!! did not arrive at that point in the documentation!